# Cannot access local var in action filter: object does not contain a definition for error

Tags: model-view-controller, local-variables, action-filter

Noob to MVC question!  Consider the following I'm using for an action filter

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;
}
```

var model contains a section I want to access. I know it's there because when I breakpoint at that point I can see.

[image]

However, when i want to :

```
string tempStr = model.Companydetails.Address;
```

I get ' object does not contain a definition ' error.  Any thoughts to what im missing here.  Thanks in advance for your time.

S

EDIT: @Leniel Macaferi. Scr shot!  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be:

```
string tempStr = model.CompanyDetails.Address1;
```

I can see that Address1 is null. I cannot see the Address property. Can you confirm that there is an Address property?

The error: object does not contain a definition for, generally is related to wrongly typed variable names in your code. Note that you're using in your code `Companydetails` when it should be `CompanyDetails` with an upper case D in Details.

Comment: Yeah i dont help myself alot when i retype things completely wrong.  the actual content for the comparison is IsValid(model.CompanyDetails.Address1)  IsValid is just a bool method returning result String.IsNullOrEmpty(Address1).

Comment: Its the fact that at breakpoint you can see the model.CompanyDetails.Address1 but when I try to use it for String.IsNullOrEmpty it throws me the 'object does not contain definition' error

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? Does not contain definition... for what? I think there's something more.

Comment: Just posted screen shot now of full error message.  Note this isnt run time now.  Simply design time.

Comment: Is your CompanyDetails class in the same namespace as the Controller class that is trying to use it?

Comment: Take a look at these links for possible solutions: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottcate/archive/2007/06/10/cs0117-type-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-identifier.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4aad8at%28v=vs.80%29.aspx and http://forums.asp.net/p/986906/1274700.aspx

Comment: Thanks Leniel for all your help.  Will do!